# Chromium-Browser Kiosk Mode

Tags: linux, google-chrome, browser, automation, kiosk

I am running a Raspberry Pi with Chromium-Browser in Kiosk mode. The purpose is to make available an ADP clock-in/clock-out Kiosk for employees in our building's entrance.

```
@/usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=https://workforcenow.adp.com/ --incognito
```

The Problem:
When a user logs out of ADP, it takes them to a log out page where is simply says, "You have logged out. To protect sensitive information, close your browser." and the URL is https://workforcenow.adp.com/public/logout_en.htm.

I would like to test for that URL then restart Chromium-Browser when triggered--OR--If the user closes the browser, I would like to relaunch it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to restart the browser when it closes by adding these lines to an executable file:

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
  /usr/bin/chromium-browser --app=https://workforcenow.adp.com/ --incognito --window-size=1280,800
done
```

Then I call that file on login.